# How to write a function that handles its argument

Tags: arguments

I would like to implement a sensible strategy for handling optional arguments.  In this instance, I want the function to be as for a function like `abbrev-mode` (although not in the context of a minor mode):

> If called interactively, toggle the
> ‘Abbrev mode’ mode.  If the prefix argument is positive, enable
> the mode, and if it is zero or negative, disable the mode.
>
> If called from Lisp, toggle the mode if ARG is ‘toggle’.  Enable
> the mode if ARG is nil, omitted, or is a positive number.
> Disable the mode if ARG is a negative number.

Have started with this simple implementation.

```
(defun roto-abbrev (&optional n)
  "Enables words to be expanded as one types."
  (interactive)
  (unless n (setq n 1))
  (abbrev-mode n))
```

How do I make it behave similar to `abbrev-mode` function with respect to its argument handling?

Comment: The question is unclear: How do you want the function  to behave? What would the user see and do? IOW, what is its specification?

Comment: IOW, you want to know *how exactly* `abbrev-mode` (or really *any* minor mode function`, since they all implement the behavior you describe) implements its  argument handling. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, want to replicate that for my function.

Comment: See if my edit reflects your goal - please revert it if it does not.

Comment: I am not focusing specifically on making minor modes, but on functions with optional argument.

Comment: OK - then you still need to explain what the function's action should be when the corresponding action of a minor mode  is "enable the mode" or "disable the mode".  What should happen if I do `M-x roto-abbrev` or I do `(roto-abbrev 'toggle)` from lisp? If `roto-abbrev` were a minor-mode function then the minor-mode would be toggled: what's the behavior you expect in this case? Similarly for all the other cases.

Comment: "How do I make it behave similar to abbrev-mode function with respect to its argument handling?" -- you would begin by looking at how abbrev-mode handles its argument.  I trust that there is an unwritten portion of this question in which you did that, found it wasn't satisfactory, but decided to omitted that code and explanation from your text.  I suggest you improve your question by restoring those things.

Comment: @ephram If you would like to discover these things yourself, it might be handy to know about `pp-macroexpand-last-sexp`. Go to the definition of `abbrev-mode` (e.g. using `xref-find-definitions`). Then place your cursor after the definition and do `M-x pp-macroexpand-last-sexp`. Now you can study yourself how the functionality has been implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point I thought I had understood what the OP wanted and edited the question to reflect that understanding, but the OP demurred and changed it back a bit, so I don't know if this will answer his current question. It is really an answer to the previous form of the question after my edit, but I still think there is a chance that this is really what the OP is after.

The basic idea is that we want a function that handles its argument exactly the way a minor mode does, so we figure out what a "real" minor mode function does and strip way all the minor mode paraphernalia, leaving only the argument handling. But the argument is supposed to enable or disable *something*, so we emulate this enabling/disabling by defining a variable and set it to `t` to "enable" or to `nil` to "disable" whatever it is we are enabling or disabling. For a "real" minor mode, the variable is a buffer-local variable with the same name as the mode function (e.g. `abbrev-mode` is the name of the mode function and also the name of the mode variable), so we follow that convention.

With that as explanation, here's a minimal function that handles its argument the way the quoted paragraph in the question describes and "enables"/"disables" whatever it is we are trying to enable/disable by setting the corresponding variable. Here's the minimal code:

```el
(defvar-local foo-bar nil)

(defun foo-bar (&optional arg)
    (interactive
     (list
      (if current-prefix-arg
          (prefix-numeric-value current-prefix-arg)
        'toggle)))

    (setq foo-bar
            (cond
             ((eq arg 'toggle) (not foo-bar))
             ((and (numberp arg) (< arg 1)) nil)
             (t t)))
    foo-bar)
```

I assume that the variable should be buffer-local here, but it could be made global: just change the `defvar-local` to `defvar`. Initially, `foo-bar` is `nil`, so it is "disabled".

The tests that @antonio describes in his answer can be used to verify that everything is as it should be: after every test, you can evaluate the `foo-bar` variable in the appropriate buffer to make sure its value is as expected.

BTW, I did this by macroexpanding a fictitious `(define-minor-mode foo-bar "foo-bar docstring")` and ruthlessly eliminating everything but the argument handling and the state variable.

Although I hope this will answer the OP's "real" question, I am not holding my breath. Depending on how it goes, I might keep it, amend it or delete it.

Comment: Correct, like `minor-mode` but with minor mode paraphernalia stripped off.

Comment: How do you make `(defun foo-bar` but also `(setq foo-bar`?

Comment: A [symbol](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Symbols.html) in Emacs Lisp has [separate value and function](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Symbol-Components.html) components.

Comment: Ok, so they are separate, with `setq` changing the value component.

Comment: What would the last `foo-bar` do?

Comment: That's what the *function* returns: the current value of the *variable* `foo-bar`.

Comment: Ok.  Thus, if I want to execute `abbrev-mode`, I can call `(abbrev-mode foo-bar)` rather than return value of variable `foo-bar`.  Right?

Comment: Uh, what? This makes no sense to me.

Comment: Anyway, this is a discussion devolving into meaningless chatter at this point. If my answer does not answer your question, just say so and I will delete it.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what is your final goal, but this replicates the behaviour described in the quoted part of your answer.
Indeed, it entails the large part of the call-type/prefix combinations, so it could be useful in different contexts.

```lisp
(defvar my-minor-mode-active nil)

(defun  my-minor-mode-set (activate)
  "Activate my-minor-mode if ACTIVATE is non-nil, else deactivate it."
  (cond
   (activate
    (setq my-minor-mode-active t)
    ;; More initialising code here
    )
   ((not activate)
    (setq my-minor-mode-active nil)
    ;; More deinitialising code here
    )))
    

(defun f (&optional prefix)
  (interactive "P")

  ;; Manage user interactive calls
  (when (called-interactively-p 'interactive)
    (cond
     ((null prefix)
      (my-minor-mode-set (not my-minor-mode-active))
      (message (concat "Inter. call with nil prefix, hence the mode is toggled to "
               (if my-minor-mode-active "active." "inactive."))))

     ((> (prefix-numeric-value prefix) 0)
      (my-minor-mode-set t)
      (message "Inter. call with positive prefix, hence the mode is activated."))
     ((<= (prefix-numeric-value prefix) 0)
      (my-minor-mode-set nil)
      (message "Inter. call with non-positive prefix, hence the mode is deactivated."))))

  ;; Manage Lisp calls (including keyboard macros)
  (when (not (called-interactively-p 'interactive))
    (cond
     ((equal prefix 'toggle)
      (my-minor-mode-set (not my-minor-mode-active))
      (message (concat "Lisp call with 'toggle prefix, hence the mode is toggled to "
               (if (not my-minor-mode-active) "active." "inactive."))))
     ((or (null prefix) (> (prefix-numeric-value prefix) 0))
      (my-minor-mode-set t)
      (message "Lisp call with nil/positive prefix, hence the mode is activated."))
     ((<= (prefix-numeric-value prefix) 0)
      (my-minor-mode-set nil)
      (message "Lisp. call with non-positive prefix, hence the mode is deactivated.")))))
```

Test is with the lisp calls:

```lisp
(f 'toggle)
(f)
(f 0)
(f 1)
(f -1)
```

And with the interactive calls:

```
M-f
C-u M-f
C-u 0 M-f
C-u 1 M-f
C-u -1 M-f
```

The requested behaviour of `(f 0)` is not immediately clear. I am assuming that non-positive prefixes trigger deactivation.

Comment: Please heed the warnings in the doc-string of `call-interactively-p`: it would be better to emulate what `define-minor-mode` does as exactly as possible, where it only uses `call-interactively-p` for notifying the user: `The only known proper use of ‘interactive’ for KIND is in deciding
whether to display a helpful message, or how to display it.  If you’re
thinking of using it for any other purpose, it is quite likely that
you’re making a mistake.  Think: what do you want to do when the
command is called from a keyboard macro?`

Comment: @NickD: Perhaps I misunderstood the OP, but he wrote "I want the function ... not in the context of a minor mode". 
As for `called-interactively-p`, do you mean replacing it with something like:
`(defun foo (&optional print-message)
  (interactive "p")
  (when print-message (message "foo")))`? 
How to distinguish here `C-u 1 M-x foo` from `(foo 1)`?
They appear to be two distinct required cases in the question.

Comment: It is not clear what the OP wants, so we are all trying to figure that out. As for `called-interactively-p` (sorry I screwed up the name in my first comment), I have never used it (never needed it really), so I have no idea if there is or not a way to distinguish the two cases you mention. But the warning in the doc seemed important enough to flag.