# abbrev-mode not being enabled with value 1

Tags: abbrev

With the following function doing (protabbrev) does not enable `abbrev-mode` even though `protabbrev-state` is `1`.  What could be the reason?

```
(defvar-local protabbrev-state nil)

(defun protabbrev (&optional arg)
  "Enable or disable the replacement of words with Abbrev."
  
  (interactive
   (list
    (if current-prefix-arg
    (prefix-numeric-value current-prefix-arg)
      'toggle)))

  (setq protabbrev-state 
    (cond
     ((eq arg 'toggle) (not protabbrev-state))
     ((and (numberp arg) (< arg 1)) nil)
     (t 1)))

  (abbrev-mode protabbrev-state))
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do. Presumably, you are following up on your previous [question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/72945/how-to-write-a-function-that-handles-its-argument) where you had a similar comment to my answer (which, somewhat to my surprise, you accepted). But the comment did not make sense to me then and the question does not make sense to me now.

Comment: What makes you think that `abbrev-mode` is not enabled? What exactly are you doing to come to that conclusion?

Comment: Yes I made sense to me using a variable to change the state.  I want to change the state for `abbrev-mode`.  But when I tried in use it on some words, the modifications are not being executed after I press space.

Comment: Ok, Have found the problem originates because although `abbrev-mode` is enabled in my init file, it does not apply to the current buffer.  So when I load emacs and get to the scratch buffer, `abbrev-mode` is still disabled there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the question of what you are trying to do remains unanswered and a mystery to me, the statement that `abbrev-mode` is not enabled is demonstrably false.

Let us assume that you have the above code in a file `protabbrev.el` which you load into a new, clean emacs  session (started with `emacs -q`) with `(load-file "/path/to/protabbrev.el")`. Then open a new file with `C-x C-f /path/to/foo.txt`. Check the mode line: it should look like this: `...(Text)...`. Now, with that as your selected buffer, call `protabbrev` with `M-: (protabbrev)`. Check the mode line: it changes from `...(Text)...` to `...(Text Abbrev)...` indicating that `abbrev-mode` is enabled in the buffer.

Comment: Ok, Have found the problem originates because although abbrev-mode is enabled in my init file, it does not apply to the current buffer. So when I load emacs and get to the scratch buffer, abbrev-mode is still disabled there.

Comment: You are right, calling `protabbrev` with `M-: (protabbrev)` on the selected buffer works.  But I was enabling `protoabbrev` in my init file rather than on the buffer.